# How can I change the backgroud and text color for the entire theme using a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the background and text color for my entire theme using a plug in.
I know it can be done from customizer but I want do learn how to do these basic tasks before I move to something else.
I do not have too much experience in "front-end development"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you could have your plugin enqueue your own stylesheet and use that to override whatever CSS rules from the theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this function in your plugin and write some css codes.

```
<?php
function add_to_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <style>
        /* Add Your Styles Hear */
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_to_wp_footer' );
?>
```